# How to access another class's method?

Tags: c#, winforms, methods

I have a WinForms application. In the main form, I coded a method that will clear all TextBoxes in whatever form is passed as a parameter. I want to call this method from another form. The following code is what I came up with after much trial/error and browsing this site. Is instantiating a new version of the main form every time the new form's clear all button is clicked good practice? If I were to make yet another form with it's own clear all button I would have to instantiate a new main form by similar practice (unless I made the method static)? Can anyone suggest alternative ways of accessing one form's method from a different form? Many thanks in advance.

Edit: I know making the method static would be a simple and effective solution, but I'm curious about using a non-static way.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public  void ClearAll(Form formToClear) //CLEAR TEXTBOXES
    {
        foreach (var box in formToClear.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            box.Text = "";
        }
    }

 }

public partial class NewItemForm : Form
{
    public NewItemForm()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

     private void clearAllButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 mainForm=new Form1();
        mainForm.ClearAll(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just create a `static` utility function that will clear a `Form`'s `TextBoxes`

Comment: Is there a reason why this method has to be a member of the main form? Why not a separate static class? Why not create an intermediate class inheriting from Form and all other would inherit from this one?

Comment: No, making new instance of main form is not at all good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to make your ClearAll method static. It is enough if you keep a global reference to your main form. You can do it in Program.cs. This is not the best way though.

```
static class Program {
    public static Form1 TheForm;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        TheForm = new Form1();
        Application.Run(TheForm);
    }
}
```

Again! Just because it can be done, it does not mean that I would encourage you doing it. This is not in the spirit of OOP.

If the only reason you would like to access a Form1's method is to clear TextBoxes, then I would recommend creating an intermediate class:

```
public class InterForm : Form
{
    public void ClearAll() //CLEAR TEXTBOXES
    {
        foreach (var box in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            box.Text = "";
        }
    }
 }
```

All other form should inherit from `InterForm`.

Comment: How would one put a global reference in Program.cs? What would it look like?

Comment: Updated with the sample.

Answer (score 2):

You should almost certainly create a static utility class with static functions. That will preserve memory by preventing unnecessary `Form1` instances from being created. Depending on the size of your Form class and the objects/variables contained within, creating a new instance just to use 1 function from that class, could eventually result in a large amount of memory being lost over time. A static method in a static class would prevent that from happening because static methods are only defined/instantiated once in the lifetime of the process, versus once-per-instance.

You should probably go with something like:

```
internal static class FormUtils
{
    internal static void ClearAllTextBoxes(Form form)
    {
        if (form == null)
            return;
        if (form.Controls.Count <= 0)
            return;
        foreach (var box in form.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            box.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, that function would be used like this:

```
public partial class NewItemForm : Form
{
    public NewItemForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void clearAllButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormUtils.ClearAllTextBoxes(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use concept of `Event` here.

Your Another form form where you want to call method of your main form should be having a Event,

while creating an instance of this form (I guess you are creating an instance of this form from main form only) you can subscribe an event of this form to your targeted method.

So whenever you are required to call that method of your main form (from your another form), you can raise that event.

see below sample code.

Suppose `Form1` is your main form

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void f2_ClearTextBoxOfForm(Form targetForm)
    {
        foreach (Control control in targetForm.Controls)
        {
            if (control is TextBox)
                ((TextBox)control).Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    private void btnShowForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.ClearTextBoxOfForm += f2_ClearTextBoxOfForm;
        f2.Show();
    }
}
```

and `Form2` is your another form from which you want to clear all textboxes of `Form1`

```
public delegate void ClearTextBoxEventHandler (Form targetForm);
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public event ClearTextBoxEventHandler ClearTextBoxOfForm;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnClearTextBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ClearTextBoxOfForm != null)
        {
            //here passing 'this' means we want to clear textBoxes of this form (Form2)
            //you can pass any Form's object of which you want to clear Textboxes
            ClearTextBoxOfForm(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not the main form that needs its textboxes cleared.

Comment: @Amit - Yes, but your comment says "//here you can clear textboxes of main form".

Comment: @Enigmativity aah yes, I should be more specific on passing Forms and clearing their textboxes, I have updated code accordingly. Thanks.